# How to get second parameter from 2D array when index 0 got selected from dropdown menu?

Tags: java, android

i have Drop down menu in my app that contain a list of strings that's made of my String 2d array index 0 :

```
        String[][] items = {



            {"(kilogram)", "1"},

            {"(gram)", "1000"},

            {"(pound)", "2.20462262"},

            {"(pound - troy)", "2.6792288807"},

            {"(carat)", "5000"},

            {"(ounce)", "35.2739619"},

            {"(ounce - troy)", "32.1507466"},

            {"(ton)", "0.001"}

        }





    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();



    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ) {

        data.add(items[i][0]);

        i++;

    }



    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getContext(), R.layout.option_tem, data);

    autoCompleteTextView.setText(arrayAdapter.getItem(0).toString(), false);

    autoCompleteTextView2.setText(arrayAdapter.getItem(0).toString(), false);

    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    autoCompleteTextView2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

here is the question , i don't know how to make my app to return the index 1 from items when the index 0 got selected from drop down menu!

i have tried this code but got nothing other than my app crashed.

```
    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {



            String firstData = autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString();

            String secondData = autoCompleteTextView2.getText().toString();



            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < items[i].length; j++) {

                    if (items[i][j] == firstData) {

                        tvResult.setText(items[i][1]);

                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: Can you share the exception?

Comment: @tiko sadly i didnt get any

Comment: If the app is crashing you can find it in Android Studio Logcat

Comment: @Tiko hi mate , i got this from debugging it :

E/mohajer.kitset: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mohajer.kitset2, PID: 4734
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""